# KeyGenerator AES implementation not found in android

Tags: java, android, security, keystore

I am new to android development and I tried to generate the secret key for encryption and decryption and store that key inside the key store.But I got the below error while the app was being run.

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyGenerator AES implementation not found
 at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:190)
 at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:183)
 at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:164)
 at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:135)
 at com.example.lakshika.seureapp.codes.KeyStore.createSecretKey(KeyStore.java:56)
 at com.example.lakshika.seureapp.codes.KeyStore.<init>(KeyStore.java:37)
```

This is the code which I have implemented.

```
public class KeyStore{
private static final String ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore";
private static String DEFAULT_KEY = "";
private java.security.KeyStore keystore;
private String TAG = "Key store";

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public KeyStore(String alias) {
    this.DEFAULT_KEY = alias;
    Log.w(TAG,"start key store:"+ DEFAULT_KEY);
    loadKeystore();
    if (getSecretKey() == null) {
        createSecretKey();
    }
}

private void loadKeystore() {
    try {
        keystore = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
        keystore.load(null);
    } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            CertificateException | KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void createSecretKey() {
    try {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator
                .getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,
                        ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
        KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder builder = new KeyGenParameterSpec
                .Builder(DEFAULT_KEY, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true);
        keyGenerator.init(builder.build());
        keyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

SecretKey getSecretKey() {
    try {
        return (SecretKey) keystore.getKey(DEFAULT_KEY, null);
    } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

If anybody knows how to solve this error, please help me.Thank you.

Comment: You set as target version Android M, but seems you are running on a device with a lower version. What version are you using?

Comment: SDK version 5.0

Comment: hi.. i read this article that help me about understanding using AES in lower android version https://proandroiddev.com/secure-data-in-android-encryption-in-android-part-1-e5fd150e316f
:)

Answer (score 2):

AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding is available since Android 23, but you are executing on Android 5 (android 21), so AES can not be used in your device

See https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#SupportedCiphers

Comment: Even though I have used Android 23 version, I got the same error

Comment: Do I need to add any dependency?

Comment: AES encryption is a functionality added to the android keystore on android 23.  If you are using 23+ then it has to work. It is a native function, it does not require additional dependencies. In previous versions you can use AES, but not the AndroidKeystore provider. It means you can use AES, but you can not generate, store and use the keys inside the AndroidKeystore